# How to get value of child component TextInput of NavigatorIOS in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, state

I have a NavigatorIOS component that contains a settings view. In that settings view is a list of settings that individually open up their own view when clicked on. When that setting is clicked on, a back arrow and a right button appear, like so:
[image: back arrow and right button]

I have a function set for when the right button is pressed called `onRightButtonPress` that is inside of my navigator's `push` function, which is called from the settings page to bind the settings page to the child. My `push` function looks like this:

```
  navHeight(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Height',
        component: Height,

        rightButtonTitle: 'Save',
        passProps: {
          units: this.state.units
        },
        onRightButtonPress: () => {
          console.warn("hey whats up hello");
          this.props.navigator.pop()}
      })
    }
```

The Height component that's rendered as a child looks like this:

```
class Height extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.settingInput}>
        <Text style={styles.inputRow}>Height: </Text>
          <TextInput ref="heightInput" 
         onChangeText={function(text){
           console.warn(text);
         }
         }/>
          <Text style={styles.inputRowRight}> m</Text>
      </View>
    );    
  }
}
```

Is there any way to access the value of the `TextInput` in the `Height` component when `onRightButtonPress` is called? My react-native version is 0.27.2 if that helps.

**Edit:** I Specifically only want to access the text written inside of the TextInput when the Save button is pressed. Basically, I don't want any props passed to the child to be updated unless it is pressed.

Comment: You can pass `onRightButtonPress.bind(this)` to _Height_ , so you can use it like `onChangeText={function(text){this.props.onRightButtonPress(text);}}`

Comment: Oh, but I specifically want the onRightButtonPress to not be called until the rightButton is pressed. This calls the onRightButtonPress every time text is changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Just to clarify, I never used react-native, just reactjs.**

Maybe you could pass a function directly to the props and assign it as a callback for the `onChangueText` of the `TextInput` component.

```
const externalGetInputText() => return this.refs.heightInput.value;


navHeight() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Height',
        component: Height,

        rightButtonTitle: 'Save',
        passProps: {
            units: this.state.units,
            internalGetInputText: externalGetInputText
        },
        onRightButtonPress: () => {
          console.warn("hey whats up hello");
          const text = externalGetInputText();
          console.warn(text);
          this.props.navigator.pop()}
    })
}

class Height extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.settingInput}>
                <Text style={styles.inputRow}>Height: </Text>
                <TextInput
                    ref="heightInput" 
                    onChangeText={this.props.internalGetInputText}
                />
                <Text style={styles.inputRowRight}> m</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Last note, I did't test it.**

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me declare externalGetInputText outside of a class. I made a global variable called cachedHeight that `onPress` updates and will be saved when `onRightButtonPress` is called. It's a hacky solution and I'm not proud of it.

Comment: If you figure out one better way ley me know =)

Comment: Will do. I feel like `bind` could be made use of like Siou's comment pointed out, just not in the way that he did it.